# Python - Xpath selenium chaining by skipping one child element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Basically, I am trying to shorten the xpath when chaining to the generic xpath but unfortunately, I just get the text of the first product instead of multiple product titles.

I fetch all products from the page using:

```
products = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="card h-100"]')
```

As seen in the below pic, I use `//h4/a` to identify the title:
[Browser Xpath results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Op9z.png)

In my automation script for each product I chain the '//h4/a' by skipping one parent element and fetching the text but unfortunately, I just get the first element, as seen in the below picture:
[Automation by shortening xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npB3j.png)

```
for product in products:
    card_text = product.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h4/a').text
    if card_text == 'Blackberry':
        card.find_element(By.XPATH, 'div/button').click()
        break
```

But with all parent child traversal xpath `div/h4/a` it works and I get results as expected as in the below picture.
[Automation script with long parent child xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSZqh.png)

I would like to know how to shorten xpath during chaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common problem. To start search down from specific node (in your case it is `product`) you need to specify this node as *context node*, so replace

```
'//h4/a'
```

with

```
'.//h4/a'
```

Answer (score 0):

First in your code you are calling card.find_element, but we I can't see this parameter.

I think you meant this:

```
for product in products:
    card = product.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h4/a')
    if card.text == 'Blackberry':
        card.find_element(By.XPATH, 'div/button').click()
        break
```

The best way to chain is like this, just place a space between the elements xpaths:

'element1 element2..'

So you can change your xpath to be:

```
card = product.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h4/a div/button')
```

Or in order to check for the text in one line:

```
card = product.find_element(By.XPATH,
 '//h4/a div/button[contains(text(),"Blackberry")]')
```